# C++: Move semantic in string#append

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I need to merge some strings to one, and for efficient reason I want to use move semantic in this situation (and of course those strings won't be used any more). So I tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string hello("Hello, ");
    std::string world("World!");
    hello.append(std::move(world));
    std::cout << hello << std::endl;
    std::cout << world << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I supposed it will output

```
Hello, World!
## NOTHING ##
```

But it actually output

```
Hello, World!
World!
```

It will result in the same thing if replacing `append` by `operator+=`. What's the proper way to do that?

I use g++ 4.7.1 on debian 6.10

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot move a `string` into *part* of another `string`. That would require the new `string` to effectively have two storage buffers: the current one, and the new one. And then it would have to magically make this all contiguous, because C++11 requires `std::string` to be in *contiguous* memory.

In short, you can't.

Comment: "C++11 requires std::string to be in contiguous memory" ... **any kind of C/C++ requires strings to be contiguous in memory**, a string is a 0 ending array of BYTEs/WORDs. So it cannot be, under any circumstance, non contiguous as you could not iterate it with `sz = str.c_str(); while(*sz){ ++sz; }`.

Comment: @Claudrian: A *conceptual* string is a sequence of characters; contiguity is not required. A string *literal* is a contiguous array of characters ending in a `\0` character. A `std::string` is also a contiguous array of characters. The SGI STL `rope` class is certainly a string, but there is no requirement on it being in contiguous memory. Indeed, that's the whole point: to have fast insertion performance at an arbitrary location.